# Unable to fetch information as 3rd party browser plugin is blocking JS to work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wanted to extract data from https://www.similarweb.com/ but when I run my code it shows (converted the output of HTML into text):

```
Pardon Our Interruption http://cdn.distilnetworks.com/css/distil.css" media="all" /> http://cdn.distilnetworks.com/images/anomaly-detected.png" alt="0" />

Pardon Our Interruption...

As you were browsing www.similarweb.com something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:

You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.

You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.

A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional information is available in this support article .

After completing the CAPTCHA below, you will immediately regain access to www.similarweb.com.

if (!RecaptchaOptions){ var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : 'blackglass' }; } 

You reached this page when attempting to access https://www.similarweb.com/ from 14.139.82.6 on 2017-05-22 12:02:37 UTC.

Trace: 9d8ae335-8bf6-4218-968d-eadddd0276d6 via 536302e7-b583-4c1f-b4f6-9d7c4c20aed2
```

I have written the following piece of code:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = "https://www.similarweb.com/"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print (soup.prettify())

# tags = soup('a')

# for tag in tags:
    # print 'TAG:',tag
    # print tag.get('href', None)
    # print 'Contents:',tag.contents[0]
    # print 'Attrs:',tag.attrs
```

Can anyone help me as to how I can extract the information?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Your code is a bit confusing :)

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.12 version

Comment: That's what I thought, but then your `print` statement will produce `SyntaxError` because you are using Python 3 syntax...

Comment: The link you provided (similarweb.com) is a home page and I'm not sure which "data" you want to "extract" from there?

Comment: It is not producing any error :)

Comment: I want to extract the <a> tags and its contents

Comment: @errata you can use `print()` in python 2.x, although it's not a function

Comment: The site has some kind of bot protection, i think you should leave it alone.

Comment: Umm so no chance as to extract the information ?? Cause i need to do it as a part of a project

Comment: @t.m.adam Yes, of course you can use `print` in Pythnon 2 :) I didn't say that you cannot :) I just tried to point out that syntax is different...

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `requests`; it failed. `selenium` seems to work.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://www.similarweb.com/')
```

Comment: Even I did the same . Sorry i didn't update the info , anyways thanks for your help Bill Bell :-) .

Comment: Any reasons as to why beautiful soup ain't working tho ??

Comment: It's not the fault of BeautifulSoup. The site you're trying to scrape can discern that you're not using a browser to interrogate it and refuses to yield proper pages. By using selenium you can animate a browser like Chrome which fools the website.

Comment: ohh okay , it was very helpful . Thanks for you help again :-)